# spring security with spring boot cant redirect after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I encountered a problem when integrating spring security with spring boot.After  Overwriting the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, I can't redirect to the successful page(wlecome.ftl) when I've accessed the login page.It's aways redirect to the login page(index.ftl) without error logs.

Is there anyting I missed?Help is aways appreciated,thanks!

> SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService detailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/welcome")//add this but not work
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/**/favicon.ico");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER");
    }
```

> Login.Controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/welcome")
    public String welcome(){
        return "user/welcome";
    }
```

> index.ftl(the login page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<@spring.url '/login' />" method="post">
    username:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
    password：<input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> welcome.ftl

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
<body>
  welcome
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solved the problem finally .`auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the successful login url and you anywhere redirect after login success. Put the:

```
defaultSuccessUrl("/user/welcome")
```

after the:

```
passwordParameter("...")
```

in your security configuration.

Comment: First of all thank you very much. I did what you said but did not work.It aways redirect to the login page.

Comment: Check again if you can. I forgot slash before "user/welcome". It should be: "/user/welcome"

Comment: I used "/user/welcome" above,but get the same result.

Comment: May be he is not getting authenticated which leads him to be redirected to the login page again.May be he should keep any page in successfulURL which doesn't require authentication

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/user/welcome",true)
```