# Spring security does not go beyond login page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am currently using thymeleaf, to implement my spring starter security.

**What I am trying to acheive:**
redirect to /userList after successful login

config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // roles admin allow to access /admin/**
    // roles user allow to access /user/**
    // custom 403 access denied handler
    // @formatter:off
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/user/userList/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/usersList", true).successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        System.out.print("enter");
                        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
                        System.out.print("session expired");
                    }
                }).permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired=true");
    }
}
```

This [link](https://github.com/lieyongchang/RepoWIthIssue.git) has my repo

Steps to recreate the issue:

1. tap the user tap on the upper right corner
2. username is user, password is generated on console of eclipse
3. it will redirect to a blank
4. inspect browser
5. error code will be shown

**What I have tried:**

I tried this method from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342040/spring-security-with-spring-boot-cant-redirect-after-login) and I change the parameter to redirect to root

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
```

but either worked.

**Expected result:**  redirect to /userList.html after successful log in

```
 .defaultSuccessUrl("/usersList", true)
```

**Actual result:** blank page with error code output in brower console (see below image)

[image]

Comment: 3a) Wait more than 60s. --- 3b) Request page reload. --- 3c) Get redirected to login page because session expired. --- There is no actual "logout", just a new login.

Comment: @Andreas I have made the following changes, I have use EnableWebSecurity instead of Configurable, now when i key in the username and password i got this error:

Comment: The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

Comment: i have also make changes to my login.html to make it very strainghtforward and simple, not styling no nothing, but th error still happens

Answer (score 0):

you can using servlet http session, this is code for set timeout :

```
HttpSession ss = request.getSession(); ss.setMaxInactiveInterval(100);
```

Comment: i change my annotation to Configuration and EnableWebSecurity and now it cant even redirect to userList.html :(

Comment: in fact, just opening loclhost:8080 , will already produce various errors such as 

The resource from “http://localhost:8080/login” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Uncaught TypeError: e.size is not a function

Comment: @user14857732 sorry my mistake , i don't see error in your question., i think you must see this tutorial for create spring security : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

Comment: it did not redirect to the url i specify in my config. I have updated my question with image